# Type guard removing string literal types

Tags: typescript

When creating a TS type guard, it seems like string literals are removed from the narrowed type once you add `undefined` or `null` to the predicate type. Is there any way to use a type guard that has a predicate like `x is 'my-string' | undefined`?

Or, in other words: Assume we have a type guard with the predicate `x is 'my-string'`. Whenever checking a variable using this guard, TS will correctly narrow the passed variable down to be the literal type `'my-string'`. However, once you change the predicate to `x is 'my-string' | undefined`, TS will narrow the type of a checked variable to `undefined`. I expected it to be `'my-string' | undefined`. Why is that? Are type guards not meant to check for string literals?

Example:
[Open in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PQKgsAUABFDqAWBTAdlArgZwJbIOZQCIAXATwAdEBxNAQwCcATARgIBooSB7NKAdywA2AqMk5EsAY0RQi8GkRlIouWo0QMZ5ROwBmnOlAycAttLqIaR5O1yIiGEfTqde6qAxeoinKAAM0yAyIOjjqvgB0kDAAkgq8%20gDWDiHI0vyyhKQU1PQMAEwEkRAgwJA6ARLinF5aOYxMABQAHgBcUDTIJACUbU1QWA4A5EamALQCWESIdDQCoxhEdDi4o1mIg1AAPuiBwaEaAN5RUOZEaHRedGiIANyQAL5lFVU12ar5zW0d3b39DgtLPBbHZBFJuI7QE52c6Xa53CCPCCQYDAKAAFSUeiELmWhmhZD%206Awbm8UGMNAS0gw52ksmkEhMZEE03cnEQDlECnJuEkswEJH6yB0LO%20smWRQZyAWUD0PgAvMo7AAxTicBpdeHlZCVLDVRVEFVqnqGRa47YBUH7KAQmBYHRQBoAWXk8HCM0CJnVUAAfFAAAzhACsXWtxxgpxhUEGGIGhNlg2OiPD0IuIL2qQY8MRkDtDrWdWYDVlXRDNqgKKgKoMIzMFis7F8st8%20o5Thcbg8vC8Pn8uzBDAi6PgsY87JEYigcjIFFQua4PEw0l8A0NeSLqq6vnY%20n69vnUOMnAAbtICOa%20-sCDLnMZMrV3iwijBJUYBIhwgJOLh15wAPwflBcFkDUHhze0Gnzd412LUtjhfTg3w-L8f3-N88GArNICAA)

```ts
/*
  When using "typeGuard1", you will notice that the guarded type, for some reason, gets narrowed down to `undefined`.
  It works fine with "typeGuard2".
*/
function typeGuard1(x: any): x is 'some-literal-string-type' | undefined {
  return true;
}
function typeGuard2(x: any): x is string | undefined {
  return true;
}

// The following setup is used to make sure the compiler does not magically infer anything.
const foo = getFoo();
function getFoo(): string | undefined {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return 'This is foo'
  }
  return undefined;
}

if (typeGuard1(foo)) {
  // For some reason, `foo` gets narrowed down to `undefined`. This does not happen if you use `isFoo2(foo)`, or if you remove "| undefined" from "typeGuard1".
  console.log(foo?.length);
}
if (typeGuard2(foo)) {
  console.log(foo?.length);
}
```

Comment: Behavior is strange... seems like removing `undefined` works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PQAg6g9gTg1gziA7gSwC4AsIFdUiwOwBMBTAM2X2MIFgAoUggY1WQnxFQE8AHYgcSwBDKIQCMACgAeALhCD8nAJSzJIZAgDkcCAFtiAWgA2aYlEGH9cVFAoBzfV14aQwAFQgAPniJkKVECCuoADedAFQxKhYUOzWWMQA3HQAvnSGkSCkEBAgALwgALKCGAB0ZkS64oogAHwgAAwlAKwgAPwgAETaekYmZhZWNvj2jsQdsgQk5JSESbR0yKQg4qMCwmLiWRCK1aG0AYxs2uklhhC2m9mKc6m0QA Seems like a bug

Comment: @isaactfa But TS is able to narrow down strings to literals. Example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDmBTKAxRAKASgG4BYAKDgFcxgoBLcdLXEQgLhmgCc6w0YAPjGoATDHF4YRgmGEoAbeTADe5GDDpwYeALIBDKAAsAdFz1gRIALaEYAPhgAGYwFYCKtephcslLmBgAcgAVQzoIDQiEEEDPAF9PHyg-ANFxSRFSMgSyck1taJRkVECoDGhA91UydQB6WpgACQwfABoYAHdDDADDEAA3Ft5+AZaYACJo8faATxBKTrpFTgwMGCMDDVhDPQijNagZgAc1gANS8qhA0+NPUEgQeQxjeRA0PGiXnrQjYnJPeowADiiBEHAA6msANZgEAddY7WDBADKMD0tEoekUM1kei4XDhUgmUxglg6ATgBKsMAARhhhmjOFAeHx1khzmUKjdPPkPogiiUaXjKiocjkgA) Why doesn't it narrow the type in this case?

Comment: @isaactfa Also, why does it work as expected once I remove `undefined` from the predicate of the guard?

Comment: Hmm, that is indeed very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, see [microsoft/TypeScript#31156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31156).  It has been fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#49625](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49625) which should be released with TypeScript 4.8.  Once this happens your code will work as intended:

[Playground link to code using TS version 4.8.0-dev.20220809](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220809#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAngBwKYHEQEMBOAJgIwAUAHgFyK5goCU15iMAzogOStwC2GAtABsYUDPlyD+rKPhhgA5v1SYOiAD6JwhDMDkZCiAN4BYAFCJE+DFBD4kMkBgDcZgL5nQkWAmTpseIgAmCmpaBiYWdmlZBXVNMG1dMH0jMwsrGztkfEcXU3dTMwgEaURgODhEAF5EeWsAMQrSejzPaHgkOqhGuGbqaLl5OK0dPQMTcxZgRFIAWVwoAAsAOnEE3mbEAD5EAAZlgFZ6VMn061skDgAVRbZIsoqONMQCs8ykEaT9PIKzGGnSMp-AQSKRynB6McJhZimBuIIMMtBHB5GCKgB+JEYBRLFpuP4AoE4EHBcGQk4wkpwBFIlFouCYhE4xZ4-JmIA)

Comment: Thank you very much! Happy to hear that this is not an error/misunderstanding on my side. Looking forward to TS 4.8 :)